# discord.py - Divinding string to list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to make so that a single string would be divided to a list, for example

```
from
words = "apple;banana;mango"

to
["apple", "banana", "mango"]
```

Im using python 3.6.8, thanks!

Comment: Specifically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/743807/10595994) contains all of the information you need.

Comment: TLDR, `words.split(';')`.