# What does line.split do?

Tags: python, file, split, line

I'm wondering what `line.split` does because I've been told it will help my code.
I'm trying to make a list consisting of the current data stored inside of an external text file.
My code goes as follows:

```
highscores = []

highscorefile = open('highscores.txt','r')
cont = highscorefile.readlines()
for line in cont:
    highscores.append(line)
highscorefile.close()
print(highscores)
```

I've been told that `line.split` will help sort it but I first need to figure out what it does.

Current output:

```
['1,3\n', '3,4\n', '6,5\n', '12,10']
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: You might want to use [strip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) as well.

Comment: what exactly is your expected output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a string into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/how-to-split-a-string-into-a-list)

Comment: I would suggest using a context manager to handle that file, and iterating over the file object directly.

Answer (score 1):

`split` is a method used on strings. It splits a string by a seperator. For example,

```
'hello world how are you'.split(' ') = ['hello', 'world', 'how', 'are', 'you']
```

Answer (score 0):

split() method returns a list of strings after breaking the given string by the specified separator.

```
word = 'geeks, for, geeks, pawan'
```

## maxsplit: 0

```
print(word.split(', ', 0))
```

Output

```
['geeks, for, geeks, pawan']
```