# This question is related to the datetime module of Python

Tags: python, python-datetime

I wrote a Python function that prints the number of days remaining in birthday of a user - the value of which is entered by the user. The code is as follows:

```
"""
Created on Thu Feb 20 16:01:33 2020
@author: hussain.ali

"""
    import datetime as dt
    import pytz
    def days_to_birthday():
        a = (input('Enter your birthday in YYYY, MM, DD format with the year being the current year:'))
        td = dt.datetime.today()
        #td2= td.replace(hour=0, minute =0, second =0, microsecond =0)
        birthday = dt.datetime.strptime(a, '%Y,%m,%d')
        days_to_birthday = birthday - td
        print("There are", days_to_birthday, ' remaining until your next birthday!')

    days_to_birthday()
```

This script or code works well except that it gives the number of days plus hours as well as minutes, seconds and even microseconds remaining until the next birthday.

**The output seems like:**

```
Enter your birthday in YYYY, MM, DD format with the year being the current year:2020,3,7
There are 15 days, 6:11:07.020133  remaining until your next birthday!
```

I want either only the days remaining to be displayed in the output 
**OR** the output as:
***There are 15 days, 6 hours, 11minutes, 07seconds, and 020133 microseconds remaining until your next birthday!***

What one needs to do to attain the desired output? Please advise.

Comment: @furas, please advice!!

Comment: change your print to `print("There are", days_to_birthday.days, 'days remaining until your next birthday!')` if you only want the days to be printed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a string into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/how-to-split-a-string-into-a-list)

Comment: Also, [this](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Comment: Why would he be spitting a string? Just use luigigi's suggestion to get the number of days from the `timedelta` object.

Answer (score 1):

change your print statement to this code below.

```
print("There are", days_to_birthday.days, 'days remaining until your next birthday!')
```

Comment: @Janine Corro, it worked,  but how can everything else(hours, minutes, seconds and microseconds) can be displayed in the o/p?

Answer (score 1):

`timedelta` doesn't have `strftime()` to format it so you can do one of two things:

1. get `total_seconds()` and calculate all values using `divmod()` or using `//` and `%`

   ```
   total = days_to_birthday.seconds
   rest, seconds = divmod(total, 60)
   hours, minutes = divmod(rest, 60)

   days = days_to_birthday.days
   microseconds = days_to_birthday.microseconds

   print('{} days {:02} hrs {:02} mins {:02} secs {:06} microseconds'.format(days, hours, minutes, seconds, microseconds))
   ```
2. get string `15 days, 6:11:07.020133`, split it and use parts to create new string

   ```
   days = days_to_birthday.days
   parts = str(days_to_birthday).split(', ')[1].replace('.', ':').split(':')

   print('{} days {} hrs {} mins {} secs {} microseconds'.format(days, *parts))
   ```

---

```
import datetime as dt
import pytz

#a = input('Enter your birthday in YYYY,MM,DD format with the year being the current year:')
a = '2020,06,01'
print('date:', a)
td = dt.datetime.today()

birthday = dt.datetime.strptime(a, '%Y,%m,%d')
days_to_birthday = birthday - td

print(days_to_birthday)

total = days_to_birthday.seconds
rest, seconds = divmod(total, 60)
hours, minutes = divmod(rest, 60)

days = days_to_birthday.days
microseconds = days_to_birthday.microseconds

print('{} days {:02} hrs {:02} mins {:02} secs {:06} microseconds'.format(days, hours, minutes, seconds, microseconds))

days = days_to_birthday.days
parts = str(days_to_birthday).split(', ')[1].replace('.', ':').split(':')

print('{} days {} hrs {} mins {} secs {} microseconds'.format(days, *parts))
```

Result

```
date: 2020,06,01
93 days, 21:35:15.056351
93 days 21 hrs 35 mins 15 secs 056351 microseconds
93 days 21 hrs 35 mins 15 secs 056351 microseconds
```