# How to create a list using the input string received

Tags: python

I have written a python code to convert string into list and then compare status of each items.

Able to convert the list as: Each field is separated by more than one spaces(or tab):

```
['abc   2/2     Running   2          5h', 'def      3/3     Running   0          6h', 'xyz       1/1     Running   0          5h']
```

1. I want to convert this into :

```
[['abc','2/2','Running','2','5h'], ['def','3/3','Running','0','6h'], ['xyz','1/1','Running','0',  '5h']]
```

2. I want to verify all the status of the items(3rd field). If status of all 3 items are `"Running"`, `flag_variable` is set to `True` else `False`.

   ```
    from pexpect import pxssh
    import pexpect

    def Login_Server(hostip,user,passwd):
      User_Info_out = []
      Cmd_Out = ' '
      try:
        Cmd = pxssh.pxssh()
        Cmd.login(hostip, user, passwd)
        Cmd_Out = Execute_Script4(Cmd)

      except pxssh.ExceptionPxssh as e:
        User_Info_out = 'None'
      return User_Info_out,Cmd_Out

    def Execute_Script4(Cmd):
        getpod_out,Cmd_Out1b = ' ', ' '
        pod_status = []
        print("********************")
        Cmd.sendline('sudo su ')
        Cmd.prompt()
        Cmd.sendline('kubectl get pods')
        Cmd.prompt()
        getpod_out  = Cmd.before
        pod_status = getpod_out.split()
        print("script output:")
        print (getpod_out)
        print("****************")
        getpod_out=getpod_out.splitlines()[3:-1]
        print(getpod_out)
        print(type(getpod_out))

    Login_Server('XXX.XXX.X.XX','usera','password')
   ```

   output:

   ```
    ********************
    script output:
    sudo su
    root@workernode8:/home/ubuntu# kubectl get pods
    NAME     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
    abc      2/2     Running   2          5h
    def      3/3     Running   0          6h
    xyz      1/1     Running   0          5h
    root@workernode8:/home/ubuntu#
    ****************
    ['abc   2/2     Running   2          5h', 'def      3/3     Running   0          6h', 'xyz       1/1     Running   0          5h']
    <type 'list'>
   ```

Comment: read something about python `split` and try again, should be pretty straight forward

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a string into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/how-to-split-a-string-into-a-list)

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is your question? You already know about ``str.split``, what problem do you have splitting ``'abc   2/2     Running   2          5h'`` into ``['abc','2/2','Running','2','5h']``? What is ``flag_variable``? Do you know how do 2. if you were to have the result of 1.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can use `split()`:

```
def check(lst):
    lst = [[i for i in s.split() if i] for s in lst]
    flag_variable = all(i[2]=='Running' for i in lst)
```

Comment: Your function should probably `return` something.

Comment: I can't be sure what the function is supposed to do.

Comment: _I want to verify all the status of the items(3rd field). If status of all 3 items are "Running", flag_variable is set to True else False._ so it should return `flag_variable` as `True` or `False`. Or just `return all(i[2]=='Running' for i in lst)`

Comment: Thanks. This code is working. When we pass the list to the function, it splits the data as expected and returns true if "Running" else False.