# Splitting a single item list at commas

Tags: python

```
MyList = ['a,b,c,d,e']
```

Is there any way to split a list (`MyList`) with a single item, `'a,b,c,d,e'`, at each comma so I end up with:

```
MyList = ['a','b','c','d','e']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a string into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/how-to-split-a-string-into-a-list)

Comment: as MyList is a list of string containing one string, you should be able to call .split on that string via MyList = MyList[0].split(',')

Answer (score 3):

Split the first element.

```
MyList = ['a,b,c,d,e']
MyList = MyList[0].split(',')
```

Out:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Comment: @ybot Consider accepting his answer, if it worked for you, by clicking the grey / green tick below the arrow of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `split` method on the string

```py
MyList = MyList[0].split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

See below

```
lst_1 = ['a,b,c,d,e']
lst_2 = [x for x in lst_1[0] if x != ',']
print(lst_2)
```

output

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```