# Splitting a string after a specific character in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, split, trim, code-splitting

I wanna split everything comes after = and assigning it into a new variable

example:

```
https://www.exaple.com/index.php?id=24124
```

I wanna split whatever comes after = which's in this case 24124 and put it into a new variable.

Comment: The strings are always going to be URL?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#str.split. Also possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/how-to-split-a-string-into-a-list

Answer (score 1):

You *can* of course split this specific string. `rsplit()` would be a good choice since you are interested in the rightmost value:

```
s = "https://www.exaple.com/index.php?id=24124"

rest, n = s.rsplit('=', 1)
# n == '24124'
```

However, if you are dealing with URLs this is fragile. For example, a url to the same page might look like:

```
s = "https://www.exaple.com/index.php?id=24124#anchor"
```

and the above split would return `'24124#anchor'`, which is probably not what you want.

Python includes good [url parsing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#module-urllib.parse), which you *should use* if you are dealing with URLS. In this case it's just as simple to get what you want and less fragile:

```
from urllib.parse import (parse_qs, urlparse)

s = "https://www.exaple.com/index.php?id=24124"

qs = urlparse(s)
parse_qs(qs.query)['id'][0]
# '24124'
```

Comment: thank u for ur great solution but could u please tell me what's ['id'][0] , how it decided the value that id takes and split it from other strings 24124#anchor

Comment: It knows how urls work, so ['id'] gets the `id` value and properly ignores the fragment starting with `#`. The reason it is a list is that you *can* have a url like  `https://www.exaple.com/index.php?id=24124&id=100`, in which case `parse_qs(qs.query)['id']` would have two values. It helps understanding this to print `parse_qs(qs.query)['id']` and see what that is in various cases.

Comment: Bro rsplit() is working totally fine but the issue is that it removes = while I need to use it again

the idea behind this i need to take the right hand side value and re-print it with other characters 

for example 
https://www.exaple.com/index.php?id=24124

I wanna take it and re-generate it again like 

https://www.exaple.com/index.php?id=//24124
or 
https://www.exaple.com/index.php?id//=24124
or 
https://www.exaple.com/index.php?id=24124"

etc ...

so I think what I need is 
https://www.exaple.com/index.php?id ( in variable )
= ( in variable )
42124 ( in variable )

Answer (score 0):

Simply you use [.split()](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and then take the second part only

```py
url = 'https://www.exaple.com/index.php?id=24124'
print(url.split('=')[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

For your specific case, you could do...

```
url = "https://www.exaple.com/index.php?id=24124"
id_number = url.split('=')[1]
```

If you want to store `id_number` as an integer, then `id_number = int(url.split('=')[1])` instead.

Comment: thanks a lot . could u please tell me what's the meaning of that [1] I mean why it's 1

Comment: @n00b_cod3r Yes. When you `url.split('=')`, it splits the string into two parts at `=` and gives out an array containing them - `['https://www.exaple.com/index.php?id', '24124']`. So in order to access to the value you're looking for, which is `24124`, its index is 1. Therefore, `url.split('=')[1]`.