# How to convert str to list and devide(split) words like separated elements of list?

Tags: pycharm

my code:

```
entered_text = input(str("Enter text - \n"))

entered_text = list(entered_text.split('. ' and ', ' and ' ' and '.'))

print(entered_text)
```

but I receive this as a result.
['text1 text2 text3 text4']
as one element, how i can devide them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a string into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/how-to-split-a-string-into-a-list)

Comment: You are asking about python's split function (https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str) . With no arguments, it will split on the blanks, i.e. making words from a sentence. Your question has already been asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/how-to-split-a-string-into-a-list

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
entered_text = input(str("Enter text = \n"))

res = entered_text.strip().split(" ")
```