# How to extract the time from one column to different separate column in hours, minute and second

Tags: python

```
Crying time
20:31:47    
23:33:46
10:20:00
11:30:00
12:15:00
20:31:47
23:33:46
 10:20:00
 11:30:00
 12:15:00
 17:45:00
 19:20:00
 19:45:00
 22:30:00
  0:22:03
11:30:00
12:15:38
15:01:06
18:12:21 
20:56:39
23:30:00
11:40:00
13:30:00
18:29:42
21:15:41
```

How to extract the time from one column to different separate column in hours, minute, and second in Python?

Comment: Can you give the output sample? And are you ok with using `pandas`?

Comment: [basic string manipulation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) or [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) should suffix, no need for machine-learning.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a string into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/how-to-split-a-string-into-a-list)

Comment: As @ggaurav said, an output example of what you want would be really helpful to understand your question. Please, update your question to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want?

Your "dat" file:

```
Crying time
20:31:47    
23:33:46
10:20:00
11:30:00
12:15:00
```

The code:

```
import re

with open("dat", "r") as msg:
    text = msg.readlines()

text = re.sub(r"[A-Za-z]","","".join(text)).replace(":"," ")

print (text)
```

Output:

```
20 31 47    
23 33 46
10 20 00
11 30 00
12 15 00
```

Your text data are in a "dat" file. You read the file line by line in a list using the readlines() method.

Then, you remove your header by using the re.sub method which replaces letters by nothing over the join product of your list (which yields a string). Finally, you replace the ":" by a space to print the output.

Alternatively, you can do:

```
with open("dat", "r") as msg:
    text = msg.readlines()

for i in range(1,len(text)):
    print (text[i].strip().replace(":"," "))
```

Which yields the same output.

Comment: ya in that way....but its very confusing ...i didnt understand it anything.....like i have a column name Crying_time and i want to slit the hour, min,and sec in differnt column of each ....then how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what data you're using as its not formatted correctly, but if it was a string you can use .split to separate each hour minute and second into a list, which you can then call one each value

```
Crying_time = "20:31:47"
print(Crying_time.split(":"))
```

Would output

```
['20', '31', '47']
```

And can be seen by using

```
print(Crying_time[0])
```

Would output

```
'20'
```

If your numbers arent a string you can use str() to convert them to a string.

```
x = 1234
x = str(x)
```

Comment: yes it was on string,but u take one value.....if i want to extract the whole column with column header Crying_time and split into differnt column with name hour, min and sec.....then how to do it ?

Comment: Can you post a sample of your code on how it is being input? is it a dictionary, a list, etc?

Comment: its a string datatype

Answer (score 0):

As I understand. You have a file to read. Let's name it `imsad.help`. This file has this content:

```
Crying time
20:31:47    
23:33:46
10:20:00
11:30:00
12:15:00
20:31:47
23:33:46
 10:20:00
 11:30:00
...(continues)
```

Then, I understand you want to separate into 3 vectors:

- hours
- minutes
- seconds

So we can store these values in 3 different lists. The code may look something like:

```py
hours = []
minutes = []
seconds = []

with open("imsad.help", "r") as fp:
    for line in fp: # Read the file, line by line
        t = line.strip() # strip removes whitespaces and new lines
        t = t.split(":") # split creates a list separating elements with ':'
                         # in between. In our case, it should create a list
                         # like: [hour, min, sec]

        if len(t) != 3:
            continue # This is the first row that contains ["Crying time"]
                     # So, we skip this and continue with other lines

        # cast to int and appends to each list
        hours.append(int(t[0]))
        minutes.append(int(t[1]))
        seconds.append(int(t[2]))

# Print only for demo
print("hours:", hours, "\n")
print("minutes:", minutes, "\n")
print("seconds:", seconds, "\n")
```

Begin learning Python:

- [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/default.asp)
- [String methods (w3schools)](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_string.asp)

References:

- [strip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip)
- [split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.split)
- [open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open)