# How do I find the longest word in a list

Tags: python, list

**I tried this:**

```
sentence = input("Sentence without punctuation: ")


lst = [sentence]
longestString = max(lst, key=len)
print(longestString)


print(len(longestString))
```

**But my output is this:**

```
sentence = input("Sentence without punctuation: ")


lst = [sentence]
longestString = max(lst, key=len)
print(longestString)


print(len(longestString))
```

Comment: You provided the code as the output...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a string into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/how-to-split-a-string-into-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to break your sentence into words, instead of this

```
lst = [sentence]
```

you'd instead want

```
lst = sentence.split()
```

Otherwise you are making a list that has a single element, which is your entire string.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace `lst = [sentence]` with `lst = sentence.split()`