# Comparing two strings for multiple outcomes

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

You will be given two sentences S1, S2 your task is to find

- a. Number of common words between S1, S2
- b. Words in S1 but not in S2
- c. Words in S2 but not in S1

I cant seem to do this problem for words , but I can do it for letters. Please help me out

example

```
S1= "the first column F will contain only 5 unique values"
S2= "the second column S will contain only 3 unique values"
```

Output:

```
a. 7
b. ['first','F','5']
c. ['second','S','3']
```

Comment: ([python - How to split a string into a list? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/how-to-split-a-string-into-a-list))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use set.

```py
a_words = set(S1.split(" "))
b_words = set(S2.split(" "))

A_ANS = len(a_words.intersection(b_words))
B_ANS = list(a_words - b_words)
C_ANS = list(b_words - a_words)
```

Comment: I tried to run the code and this happened "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: def string_features(S1, S2):
   
    a_words = {S1.split(" ")}
    b_words = {S2.split(" ")}

    a = len(a_words.intersections(b_words))
    b = list(a_words - b_words)
    c = list(b_words - a_words)
    return a,b,c
 



    

S1= "the first column F will contain only 5 uniques values"
S2= "the second column S will contain only 3 uniques values"
a,b,c = string_features(S1, S2)
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)

Comment: I have changed code a bit, please try again.