# I have a string "hello\n1hello123\n2yahoo". Want to split it with \n[integer value]

Tags: python, list, split

I have a string in python.

```
str1 = "hello\n1hello123\n2yahoo"
```

I would like to split this with \n[integer value] to get a list that looks like:
[hello, hello123, yahoo]

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Could you not `.split('\n')` and then post-process from there?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/how-to-split-a-string-into-a-list

Comment: https://www.mycompiler.io/view/75Q4Vb7 check this out

Comment: Refer docs on `re.split`

Answer (score 0):

As someone who goes too far in avoiding regular expressions (avoiding them whenever possible rather than simply avoiding them when they are inappropriate), I would lean towards splitting on `\n` and processing the resulting list element by element:

```
from string import digits

result = [x.lstrip(digits) for x in str1.split("\n")]
```

If you are less regex-averse than I, and as recommended in the comments,

```
from re import split
from string import digits

results = split(f'\n[{digits}]*', str1)
```

Answer (score 0):

regular expression package

```
enter code here
str1 = "hello\n1hello123\n2yahoo"
import re
print(re.split(r"\n[1-9]", str1))
```