# How to split a single value list to multiple values in same list

Tags: python

I did some workarounds but none of them worked so here I am with a question on how can we split a value from a list based on a keyword and update in the same list

```
    here is my code,
    result_list = ['48608541\ncsm_radar_main_dev-7319-userdevsigned\nLogd\nG2A0P3027145002X\nRadar\ncompleted 2022-10-25T10:43:01\nPASS: 12FAIL: 1SKIP: 1\n2:25:36']
```

what I want to remove '\n' and write something like this,

```
result_list = ['48608541', 'csm_radar_main_dev-7319-userdevsigned', 'Logd', 'G2A0P3027145002X', .....]
```

Comment: You can use [`split()` to split a string to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/how-do-i-split-a-string-into-a-list-of-words): `result_list = result_list[0].split('\n')`

Comment: The input value for result_list is a Python list comprised of one element which is a string. What would the output look like if the input list had more than one element?

Answer (score 1):

You need to `split` each of the string by `\n` which results in a list that you need to flatten. You can use list-comprehension:

```py
>>> [x for item in result_list for x in item.split('\n') ]
# output:
['48608541', 'csm_radar_main_dev-7319-userdevsigned', 'Logd', 'G2A0P3027145002X', 'Radar', 'completed 2022-10-25T10:43:01', 'PASS: 12FAIL: 1SKIP: 1', '2:25:36']
```

Answer (score 0):

this will split each element of your list at \n and update in same list

`result_list = [item for i in result_list for item in i.split('\n') ]`

Answer (score 0):

Solution using regex (re):

```
import re    
result_list = re.split('\n', result_list[0])

#output: 
['48608541', 'csm_radar_main_dev-7319-userdevsigned', 'Logd', 'G2A0P3027145002X', 'Radar', 'completed 2022-10-25T10:43:01', 'PASS: 12FAIL: 1SKIP: 1', '2:25:36']
```

Comment: This is correct inasmuch as it will work but *re* is unnecessary for this trivial case

Answer (score 0):

The `split()` method of the `str` object does this:

> Return a list of the words in the string, using sep as the delimiter string.

```
>>> '1,2,3'.split(',')
['1', '2', '3']
```

so here we have the answer as follows:

```
string_object = "48608541\ncsm_radar_main_dev-7319-userdevsigned\nLogd\nG2A0P3027145002X\nRadar\ncompleted 2022-10-25T10:43:01\nPASS: 12FAIL: 1SKIP: 1\n2:25:36"

result_list = string_object.split(sep='\n')
```