# Looking for list of elements with string type

Tags: python

I have columns of data which I copied from some source, so wanted to do some manipulations with the columns  but the copied data looks like below x1,x2,x3,....x100. I wanted to convert this data into string type like 'x1','x2','x3',...'x100'.

Input data(copied data) :

```
x1,x2,x3
```

Looking for output(list format):

```
['x1','x2','x3']
```

Comment: You forgot to include your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: Does the list contain variables called `x1, x2, x3, ..., x100`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I split a string into a list of words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/how-do-i-split-a-string-into-a-list-of-words)

Answer (score 1):

To convert a sequence of column names like x1,x2,x3,...,x100 into a string format like 'x1','x2','x3',...,'x100', you can split the column names using the comma as a delimiter, add single quotes around each column name, and then join them back into a single string. Here's how you can do it in Python:

```
# Sample input data

column_names = 'x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x100'

# Split the column names by comma and strip any leading/trailing whitespace

columns_list = [column.strip() for column in column_names.split(',')]

# Add single quotes around each column name

quoted_columns = ["'" + column + "'" for column in columns_list]

# Join the quoted columns into a single string

result_string = ','.join(quoted_columns)

print(result_string)
```

Output:

**'x1','x2','x3','x4','x5','x100'**

In this example, column_names is the input string containing the column names separated by commas. We split the string into a list of column names, add single quotes to each column name, and then join the quoted column names back into a single string using the join() method.

Now, result_string will contain the desired string with column names in the format 'x1','x2','x3',...,'x100'. You can apply this method to your data to manipulate the column names as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying @yousef answer has worked for me

```
col_names = 'x1,x2,x3'
new_col = [str(x) for x in col_names.split(',')]
```

Comment: str() is redundant as x is already a string

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).