# Last word is not appending in the list

Tags: python, split

I wrote the code of returning the words in a string into a list. But the code is not appending the last word in the string. Here I tried to replicate the split() method for strings. What will be the corrected code?

```
def splitstring(s):
    a = []
    count = ''
    for i in s:
        if i == ' ':
            a.append(count)
            count = ''
        else:
            count += i
    return a

# Input = 'Hello World'
# Expected output = ['Hello', 'World']
# Actual = ['Hello']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I split a string into a list of words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/how-do-i-split-a-string-into-a-list-of-words)

Comment: This code will only append the characters after discovering a whitespace (" ")
In case a string is not ending with whitespace, it will not append the last substring. You need to append i to list after completion of for loop

Comment: `count` is a weird choice of variable name.

Comment: \**[Hello, World!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program)*

Comment: You have a remaining `count` string at the end of the loop because there is no trailing space to trigger its addition to `a`.   One way to fix it would be to add a space to `s` in the for loop: `for i in s+' ':`

Answer (score 1):

Your current implementation doesn't handle the last word in the string, because it only appends the word to the list when it encounters a space.
To fix this problem, you can do this:

```
def splitstring(s):
    a = []
    count = ''
    for i in s:
        if i == ' ':
            a.append(count)
            count = ''
        else:
            count += i
    if count:  # Add this condition to handle the last word
        a.append(count)
    return a
```

Though, I suggest you to use Python's built-in functions. They are well optimized and reliable.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any second match for `if i == ' ':`.

Quick fix:

```
def splitstring(s):
    a = []
    count = ''
    for i in s:
        if i == ' ':
            a.append(count)
            count = ''
        else:
            count += i
    a.append(count)
    return a
```